# Zend __construct Fatal Error

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to intetegrate `Zend_Acl` in my application:

```
class AuthController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function __construct (Zend_Auth $auth, Zend_Acl $acl)
    {
        $this->_auth = $auth;
        $this->_acl  = $acl;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Declaration of AuthController::__construct() must be compatible with
>   that of Zend_Controller_Action_Interface::__construct() in....

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the signature for Zend_Controller_Action_Interface::__construct() look like?

Comment: It seems the interface holds a declaration for your constructor and you are not allowed to have constructor arguments.

Comment: so.... :) I am not sure what to do

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10775426/131824

Answer (score 0):

`Zend_Controller_Action_Interface` for constructor looks like this:

```
public function __construct(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request,
                            Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract $response,
                            array $invokeArgs = array());
```

This means that your class must have same declaration for constructor

Comment: I found this in the documentation, but I does not understand it. Can you explain it?

Comment: If you know what `controller action` is then you understand that it processes web request. So it's obvious that it requires some arguments like `$request` to work.

Comment: It means that your constructor cannot take any arguments not defined in the interface it has inherited from `Zend_Controller_Action_Interface`.

Comment: Explain what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I just do some tutorials to get rid of acl and integrate it in my project... I will close the question :) It seams to be not the best tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't change the constructor, you will have to pass your ACL in a different way. Also keep in mind that you can access `Zend_Auth` at any time by calling `Zend_Auth::getInstance()`.

To access your ACL, you can use `Zend_Registry`. If you are defining your ACL in a bootstrap, place it in the registry. You can then access it through the registry, or even write a new class, which extends `Zend_Controller_Action`, that provides a method to retrieve the ACL.

Answer (score 0):

You never initiate controller instance since its the job Zend_Controller_Front to do it for you hence you cannot use its constructor . But what you can do is use Zend_Registry instead

inside your Bootstrap.php

```
Zend_Registry::set('acl',$acl);
Zend_Registry::set('auth',$auth);
```

In your controller

```
public function init()
{
  $this->_acl = Zend_Registry::get('acl');
  $this->_auth = Zend_Registry::get('auth');
}
```

This init function act as the constructor .

Answer (score 0):

you could use a plugin:

```
//This class effectively extends Zend_Controller_Front
//This plugin will dispatch with every request and provide user access control
//based on credentials provided at login.
class MY_Controller_Plugin_Acl extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
        parent::preDispatch($request);
        //setup ACL
        $acl = new Zend_Acl();
        //add Roles
        $acl->addRole('guest');
        //add Resources
        $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('default'));
        //set up access rules, everyone has access to the index page and the error page.
        $acl->allow(NULL, array('index', 'error'));
        $acl->allow(NULL, array('index', 'index'));
        //a guest can only read content and login
        $acl->allow('guest', 'page', array('index'));
        //more ...
        //fetch current user, $auth is set in loginAction()
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
            $identity = $auth->getIdentity();
            $role = strtolower($identity->role);
        } else {
            $role = 'guest';
        }
        $module = $request->getModuleName();
        $controller = $request->getControllerName();
        $action = $request->getActionName();

        if (!$acl->isAllowed($role, $module, $controller, $action)) {
            if ($role == 'guest') {
                $request->setControllerName('user');
                $request->setActionName('login');
            } else {
                $request->setControllerName('error');
                $request->setActionName('noauth');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

register the plugin in application.ini:

```
resources.frontController.plugins.acl = "My_Controller_Plugin_Acl"
```

This is just one (simple)implementation, there are many ways to skin this cat.

Hope this helps.